# How to manually initialize std::list 's objects in C++? What to do if a pointer of class has a member list<>, can not use new?

Tags: c++, constructor, std, stdvector, stdlist

Suppose this is a struct/class in c++

```
struct MyClass{
  list<int> ls;
};
```

Now maybe due to some reason, it is not possible to initialize pointer of 'MyClass', and the memory is being allocated manually

```
MyClass *pointer = calloc(1, sizeof(MyClass));
pointer->ls.push_back(123); // <----- this line causes core dump
```

Although it works fine with pure C++ method like this:-

```
MyClass *pointer = new MyClass;
pointer->ls.push_back(123);// All good, no problem
```

**So is there any function available in std::list to resolve this issue?**

I tried doing the same with std::vector, by there was no problem in that when I used calloc()

```
struct MyClass{
  vector<int> ls;
};
MyClass *pointer = calloc(1, sizeof(MyClass));//using calloc
pointer->ls.push_back(123); // All Good
```

But on doing this using malloc:-

```
struct MyClass{
  vector<int> ls;
};
MyClass *pointer = malloc(1, sizeof(MyClass));//using malloc
pointer->ls.push_back(123); // Core dump :-(
```

Comment: Using `calloc` to allocate a non-POD object is not good practice, but if you must do it you can use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to ensure the correct constructor is called on the memory you provide. You also have to call the destructor yourself manually before you free the memory.

Comment: Do you understand that the sizeof(MyClass) reports (on my system) 24 bytes, even when there is no data in the list, and regardless of the data element size, and ls.size() reports 0 ?  The data of a std::list is allocated in dynamic memory.  The object  'ls' (generally on the automatic memory) contains attributes to keep track of list element dynamic memory location and size, but (usually) not the elements of the list.    I think your crash occurs because calloc does not invoke the std::list ctor.  Don't use 'c' allocations.  Use the various forms of c++ new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ differentiates between memory and objects in that memory. You are allocating memory with `malloc` or `calloc`, but you are not creating any object in the memory you allocated.

You can manually create an object in allocated storage using the placement-new expression:

```
new(pointer) MyClass /*initializer*/;
```

This creates a new `MyClass` object at the storage location that `pointer` points to. `/*initializer*/` is the optional initializer for the object and has the same meaning as in a variable declaration

```
MyClass my_class /*initializer*/;
```

You may need to `#include<new>` to use the placement-new form I used above and you need to make sure that the allocated memory block is large enough and sufficiently aligned for the `MyClass` object type.

Using a pointer as if it points to an object even though none was created at the storage location causes undefined behavior, which you are observing. Note that this is true for *any* (even fundamental) types *technically*. Probably that will change in the future to allow at least trivial types (or some similar category) to be created implicitly when used, but for non-trivial class types such as the standard containers, this certainly will not change.

---

Also note that `malloc` and `calloc` return `void*`, which in C++ cannot be implicitly cast to a different pointer type. You need to cast it explicitly:

```
MyClass *pointer = static_cast<MyClass*>(malloc(sizeof(MyClass)));
```

or rather than doing that, save the pointer as `void*` without any cast to hint at you that it is not actually pointing to an object, but just memory.

You can still pass that `void*` pointer to the placement-new and the placement-new will actually return you a pointer of the correct type pointing to the new object (there are some specific cases where you are actually *required* to use this pointer):

```
void *mem_ptr = malloc(sizeof(MyClass));
auto obj_ptr = new(mem_ptr) MyClass /*initializer*/;
```

---

You should also avoid using `malloc` and `calloc` and the like. C++ has its own memory allocation function, called (confusingly) `operator new`. It is used like `malloc` (initializing the memory to zero like `calloc` does is not useful, because the initializer in the placement-new can and/or will do that):

```
void* pointer = operator new(sizeof(MyClass));
```

and its `free` analogue is:

```
operator delete(pointer);
```

It still only allocates memory and does not create object as the placement new does.

---

The non-placement new expression `new MyClass;` allocates memory (by call to `operator new`) *and* creates an object as if by the placement-new form mentioned above.

---

You do not need to bother with all of this though, because you can just use a smart pointer and initialize it later, if you need that:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr; // No memory allocated or object created

ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(/*constructor arguments*/); // Allocates memory and creates object

// Object is automatically destroyed and memory freed once no `std::unique_ptr` references the object anymore.
```

You should not use raw pointers returned from `new`, `malloc` or the like as owning pointers in the first place. `std::unique_ptr` has the correct ownership semantics by default and requires no further actions by you.

Comment: suppose in the class myclass{list<int> ls; funtion intit(){....};} , I have made this function init(), so that if the program simply need to use that function init() instead of using the respective constructor. Actually I want to do it in making this class easy to use 'https://github.com/rishavbhowmik/BufferLibrary', check out the platform_init() [in line 80]function in Buffer.h of this repository, that is where I want to do it, just to initialise list<BufferPiece> pieces manually

Comment: @RishavBhowmik You cannot use a `std::list` without calling one of its constructors first. The same goes for all class type objects. I am not sure what you mean with "*initialise list<BufferPiece> pieces manually*". The `list` object is independent from the element objects it manages. You allocate and initialize a new `BufferPiece` with `emplace_back`. `std::list` does not offer a method to pre-allocate memory for elements. If you want that you need to use a different container.